# INNER Tag Avoid, Android webservices

Tags: php, android

i have one webservices(in PHP) i need to parse it so simply i need tag name. so when i **viewsource** it in browser i got ... some span tag are there and it stuch to display data so how can i avoid this?

```
<weeklyparties>
<details>
<details>
<status>
<weeklypartyid>13</weeklypartyid>
<weeklypartytitle>Thursdays</weeklypartytitle>
<weeklypartydesc><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Rare Rooftop - Chelsea</span><br></weeklypartydesc></status></details><details><status><weeklypartyid>14</weeklypartyid><weeklypartytitle>Fridays</weeklypartytitle><weeklypartydesc><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Bar Basque</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Forum</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Ganzevort Park</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Hudson Terrace</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"></span><br></weeklypartydesc></status></details><details><status><weeklypartyid>15</weeklypartyid><weeklypartytitle>Saturdays</weeklypartytitle><weeklypartydesc><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Aspen Social Club</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Bar Basque</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Crimson</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Forum</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Lexicon</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">
Lounge 16 (New Highbar)</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Hudson Bar</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\">Hudson Terrace</span><br style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color: #FFFFFF;\"><span style=\"font-family: Tahoma; color:
```

Comment: Do you control the web service?

Comment: no its already build and may be if i am send request then i can., but fist priority at my side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asume you want to develop a Java or Android application. In this case you can use a third party library for HTML parsing,like

- jsoup (see http://jsoup.org/)
- HTML Parser (see http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/)

To find all the weeklypartydesc with jsoup, you would use the following code fragment:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://your.url/").get();
Elements partyDesc = doc.select("weeklypartydesc");

for (Element entry : partyDesc)
{
    // all the weeklypartydesc as string
    Log.i(entry.text().toString());
}
```

This code also removes the br and span elements. You can easily find additional infos on using jsoup on StackOverflow (even in combination with Android). Do not forget to give your application the internet permission.

Answer (score 0):

You have not written in your question which tag name you need. I assume you're looking for `<weeklypartydesc>` and you want to get the plain text out of it there.

Additionally as you use the *view source* from your browser, I assume that there is some CDATA element you don't see (as otherwise the XML would just be invalid).

You can do this with `DOMDocument`. First obtain the element you're interested in, then convert the HTML data inside that element into plain-text by stripping tags:

```
# obtain the element in question
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

foreach($xp->query('/weeklyparties/details/status/weeklypartydesc') as $weeklypartydesc)
{
    # obtain the HTML inside that element and convert it into plain text
    $text = strip_tags($weeklypartydesc->nodeValue); # Rare Rooftop - Chelsea
}
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Z3zbpi)

If `strip_tags` does not fit your needs, you can create a `DOMDocument` out of the HTML fragment and use `XPath` to obtain all text nodes which will give you the HTML as plain text as well.